# Scrollview scrolls to origin when child is focused

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have a `View (RelativeLayout)`, managed by a `ScrollView`.

The view holds an `EditText`. Whenever the `EditText` gets focused, either by click or a call of `requestFocus()` on it, the `ScrollView` jumps back to its top position. How is it possible to make the `ScrollView` stay at its actual position?
The code is as follows:

```
public class MyView extends RelativeLayout{
public MyView(Context context){
    super(context);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int)(4 * 600));
    lp.height = (int)(3000);
    lp.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    setLayoutParams(lp);
    setBackgroundColor(0xddeeeeee);
    EditText editText = new EditText(getContext());
    editText.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(150, 150));
    editText.setX(200);
    editText.setY(400);
    editText.setBackgroundColor(0xff0000aa);
    addView(editText);
}
```

and the activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final LinearLayout listView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.project_list);
    ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(getApplicationContext());
    MyView view = new MyView(getApplicationContext());
    scrollView.addView(view);
    listView.addView(scrollView);
}
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: post screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you want your entire layout pan up than you should use :

**SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN**

meaning:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

add these line to your Relative Layout which is inside Scroll View